# Advice needed for R package security in production

Tags: r, security, package

I am working as a Data Scientist for a small start up and we are using R as part of our platform for analysis, dashboards etc. Therefore, I need to ensure that we maintain security with each package we use and load.

I have looked around and done extensive searching and have come across the following links:

- [This](https://blog.rstudio.com/tags/security) is the official R Studio Blog Security update page.
- [This](https://www.r-bloggers.com/use-github-vulnerability-alerts-to-keep-users-of-your-r-packages-safe/) blog post shows how you can implement rJava to help with those packages that require it, though it does state that '...the integrity & safety of the R package ecosystem is still in the “trust me, everything’s !!”'
- [This](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/08/good-advice-for-security-with-r.html) post gives some good advice for package security, but basically boils down to: if you get it from CRAN or another trusted source then it should be ok.
- [The CVE site](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/36163/R-Project-R.html?vendor_id=16189) lists vulnerabilities, though the last one was back in 2017.

However, all the above links essentially say the same thing, which is "if its from CRAN (or similar), then it is probably fine". Now this might indeed be the case, but I was hoping for something a bit more rigorous. Has anyone else come across this issue with production R deployment?

If possible, if someone could direct to where I might be able to find out more information on checking for security updates, breaches and changes for R packages, or how to go about testing the security myself, I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if that is what you are asking for, but one advice could be to keep the R code separated from the user using SSL and requiring authentication. See e.g. https://qunis.de/how-to-make-a-dockerized-plumber-api-secure-with-ssl-and-basic-authentication/

Comment: @KarstenW. thanks for that! I will have a read into it, but I think it is a slightly different (although still important!) security issue. I am more concerned about the R packages themselves having security holes in them that others could exploit in potentially nefarious ways. I know this is unlikely, but have to do my due diligence. But I will definitely read the article you posted :)

Comment: If you use any code that you haven't personally written then you can't trust it. That even goes down to compilers. And even compilers that you have the source code for. https://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/04/15/strange-loops-dennis-ritchie-a

Comment: This might also be of interest: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-certification-for-r-package-quality/. You can find packages that Linux Foundation's Core Infrastructure Initiative Best Practices, which might reduce the odds of security problems.